# Fetch data from SQLite and show into RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

**Hello Guys,**
I am trying to build an application for my company. I have stored data into SQLite. In the search interface I can search from database & find the results on a simple TextView. But I want to view the actual result by using RecyclerView. I have attached my code here & also adapter class.
The problem is I can't view the query data into RecyclerView. Please help me to do this.

> 1. MainActivity.java

```
public class Client extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = Client.class.getSimpleName();
    ClientDatabase db;
    ClientModel clientModel;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    Context context;
    Button search_button;
    EditText search_word;
    TextView search_result;
    RecyclerView recycler_view;
    FinalAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<ClientModel> clients = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        db = new ClientDatabase(this);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        search_word = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_word);
        search_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.search_result);
        search_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);

        search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showResult(v);

            }
        });

        RequestData();
    }

        private void RequestData() {
    Log.d(TAG, "RequestData: Requesting Data from API");
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    String url = getResources().getString(R.string.url);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray info = response.getJSONArray("response");
                ClientDatabase clientDatabase = new ClientDatabase(getApplicationContext());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Inserting data into Database");

                for (int i =0; i<info.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    ClientModel clientModel = new ClientModel();
                    clientModel.setClient_name(jsonObject.getString("client_name"));
                    clientModel.setAddress(jsonObject.getString("address"));
                    clientModel.setNote(jsonObject.getString("note"));
                    clientModel.setCp_name(jsonObject.getString("cp_name"));
                    clientModel.setCp_phone(jsonObject.getString("cp_phone"));
                    clientModel.setCp_email(jsonObject.getString("cp_email"));
                    clientModel.setAssign_person_name(jsonObject.getString("assign_person_name"));
                    clientDatabase.AddClient(clientModel);
                    clients.add(clientModel);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in saving",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

    private void _All() {
        Log.d(TAG, "_All: Clients in ready");
        Cursor cursor = db.ViewData();

    }

    private void showResult(View view){
        try {

            String word = search_word.getText().toString();
            search_result.setText("Result for : " + word + ":\n\n");

            //search for word in the database
            Cursor cursor = db.search(word);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
                int index1, index2, index3, index4;
                String result;
                do {
                    // Don't guess at the column index. Get the index for the named column.
                    index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(db.COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME);
                    // Get the value from the column for the current cursor.
                    result = cursor.getString(index1);
                    // Add result to what's already in the text view.
                    search_result.append(result + "\n");
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
            } else {
                search_result.append(getString(R.string.no_result));
            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initRecyclear(){
        recycler_view = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        adapter = new FinalAdapter(context, clients);
        recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        db.RemoveData();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

> 2. FinalAdapter.java

```
public class FinalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FinalAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<ClientModel> clientModelList;

    public FinalAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ClientModel> clientModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.clientModelList = clientModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.client_inflater, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.name.setText(clientModelList.get(position).getClient_name());
        holder.phone.setText(clientModelList.get(position).getCp_phone());
        holder.email.setText(clientModelList.get(position).getCp_email());
        holder.assigned.setText(clientModelList.get(position).getAssign_person_name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name, phone, email, assigned;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.client_name);
            phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.client_phone);
            email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.client_email);
            assigned = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.assign_name);
        }
    }
}
```

> 3. Screenshots

[image]

Comment: Just follow https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0 and you'll be good to go

Answer (score 1):

**You missed two points:**

1. To initiate `initRecyclear()` inside of onCreate block
2. To populate your `clients` ArrayList

**Solution**

Call `initRecyclear()` from `onCreate()` method:

```
initRecylear();
search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showResult(v);

        }
    });
```

Then Populate your clients list inside of `RequestData()` method

```
 private void RequestData() {

    ClientModel cmObj = new ClientModel();
    //Here Fetch your Data and put it to ClientModel object cmObj then add this object into your clients ArrayList
    clients.add(cmObj);
    //After Completion on data preparation call below method to notify your recycler 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

finally Call `RequestData()` method from `onClick` event

```
search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RequestData();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Bro thanks for your kind effort. But on `RequestData()` method i am receiving data from api and saving data into database, and on ` showResult()` method i am showing the search result on TextView. The matter is when I will click the button `search_button` the reslut will be shown in **recyclerview**. If you understand my problem please notify me.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion but nothing happened. What I will do now ?

Comment: @Faruk Ahmed: Please share your RequestData() method

Comment: @Faruk, Please follow my answer. you populate list on RequestData Method. So call this method from onClick event instead of calling showResult(v). And initRecycler() placed on your onCreate method. finally add  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on RequestData() method after completion for loop